# How to calculate one value for multiple transaction in a day using excel or python

Tags: python, excel, transactions

I am having trouble in calculating a the 'final value' column in the below table. Imagine you have a text column 'sample_card' which has multiple transactions over a month. Now, a particular card is eligible for one txn per day only. Maximum discount VALUE PER TXN is set at 75. I have to determine what value a particular card is eligible for discount.
I have more than 30000 such records. Need some formula to get the column 'Final_value'.

I have tried using countif, it didn't work. I tried concatenating date and sample_card , and then countif (sample_card all column, sample_card that row's column). It didn't work.
Kindly help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bOQt.png)

Comment: show your countif expression - then we may be able to work out what you are doing.

Comment: Excel has COUNTIFS() for cases with multiple criteria

Comment: countif (A:A,A2) 
where A denotes a concatenate column of (Sample_cardno + (#day)) to determine any multiple txn on the same day.

Comment: any help for this post?